# Is there an error in Drupal with hook_views_post_execute?

Tags: views, 8

In D8 I would like to sum a field in a view within a custom module called nvgh.
I choose to use a hook for a start. I'm not sure this will be the good hook anyway.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_post_execute/8.6.x

```
function nvgh_views_post_execute(ViewExecutable $view) {

  if ($view->total_rows > 12) {
    \Drupal::messenger()
      ->addStatus(t('You have more than 100 hits. Use the filter settings to narrow down your list.'));
  }
}
```

I directly get an error:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   TypeError: Argument 1 passed to nvgh_views_post_execute() must be an
>   instance of ViewExecutable, instance of Drupal\views\ViewExecutable
>   given in nvgh_views_post_execute() (line 96 of
>   modules\custom\nvgh\nvgh.module).

- a) Is this a bug in Drupal 8?
- b) Which hook is common to use for pseudo code like

  for each row in view result

  - count a field
  - display a message

Comment: This is a general php language issue so off topic here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the statement of `ViewExecutable` like `use \Drupal\views\ViewExecutable`

```
use \Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;

function nvgh_views_post_execute(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->total_rows > 12) {
    \Drupal::messenger()
      ->addStatus(t('You have more than 100 hits. Use the filter settings to narrow down your list.'));
  }
}
```